# Using Linux redirect to file command in Python

Tags: python, linux

I want to write the output of the `free` command of Linux to a file using Python.

I have tried the following but it did not help:

```
 from subprocess import call
    call(["free",">","myfile"])

    f = open('myfile','w')
    f.write(subprocess.call(["free"]))
```

I am new to Python so can someone guide me here to write the free command output to a file using Python?

Also, the Python I use is 2.4.

I work in a company that uses python 2.4

Comment: Why are you using such an antique version of Python when you're a new user.  You should be using 2.7 if you're sure you need Python 2.x, and you should probably be learning Python 3.x instead, anyway.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason is CentOS 5 :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker You would certainly install Python 2.6 from the EPEL repository then.

Comment: Or if you are hellbent on "ugly and familiar over correct and efficient", maybe `subprocess.call(["sh", "-c", "free > myfile"])` (or the moral equivalent with `shell=True`).

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

f = open('myfile', 'w')
subprocess.call('free', stdout=f)
f.close()
```

In newer versions of Python, one would use `with` to close the file, and `check_call` to trap errors in the `free` command.  But you say you're stuck with Python 2.4, so there you go!

Comment: I get the following error.Does this work with python 2.4? I cannot upgrade to latest python version because my company uses this.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "memcheck.py", line 5, in <module>
    f.write(subprocess.check_output('free'))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'

Comment: @user2990927: OK, updated so it hopefully will work with your ancient Python.  Maybe time for a new job.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is of python2.7

```
f.write(str(call(["free", ">", "myfile"])))
```

by this you can write the output of command in `myfile`.

```
from subprocess import call
f = open('myfile','w+')       # if you willing to read it simultaneously
f.write(str(call(["free", ">", "myfile"]))) # convert the data coming from shell to string using `str()` function.

f.seek(0)  # Reading from start set pointer to start of the file.
print f.read()
```

Comment: You should not include the redirection in the command if you are writing the file yourself.  It's just a syntax error now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `subprocess.Popen` for this.

Example:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "date"
fname = "output"

with open(fname, 'w+') as outf:
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=outf)
```

File access without with-statement:

```
outf = open(fname, 'w+')
try:
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=outf)
finally:
    outf.close()
```

And yes, you should update your Python version.

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Please also have a look at these sections of the documentation for details on usage and examples for different common use cases:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module